# tableau use either Country or State (only if country = usa) field as filter

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I am trying to display travel expenses by location in a Tableau map.  If the country = USA, then I want to filter by State, else filter by Country.  I can do either or but not both on the same map.  Where would I put this criteria?

I am new to both Tableau and to this website.  I have tried to upload an image but was told my reputation needed to be a 9.  Is there any other way to share information?  Possibly dropbox?

Here is a link to my workbook:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/Travel_country/Sheet1#!/publish-confirm

Comment: That depend entirely on how you database is structured. We can't know how it looks like if you don't tell us

Comment: I have a column for country code and one for state code.  Only rows with USA as the country have a state.  The others are blank.  There is another column with Amount spent.  The other columns are not being used as of now.  There are around 1100 rows with more than half being in the US. I am brand new to Tableau - what else would you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty simple then. You can use both [Country] and [State] as filters. If you try to filter by state on a country different from US, nothing will happen.

If you have Tableau 9.0, you can even make the Country filter influence the State filter, meaning, you will only see the State options if you select US in the Country filter.

If you need anything different, please clarify

Comment: I tried this but I cannot get it to display the way I would like.  If I just apply the country filter, It includes all the countries with expenses correctly.  If I add the state filter, I only get the US and it doesn't even break out the expenses by state.  If I just use the state filter, I get all the states with expenses in color but nothing else.

Comment: I cannot help you unless you tell what you did. Sharing a .twbx or putting some screenshots could help a lot

Comment: I would share both, but I cannot find a way to share a file here.